# Where to find synchronization service logs while syncing of Outbound email db to subscription db

Tags: outbound-email, audience-manager

I am facing difficulties to sync my subscription database and audience manager database.
I have configured subscription datatabse ,I have created a synchronization target in CME,Configured it in my publication.Is there anything else i need to do?
My profile sync application says :
The following warnings were raised while testing for configuration problems:

> The server returned a status of 404 when verifying the URL
> 'MailOpened.gif'. This may be okay if the Tracking page is in a
> different directory.
>
> The server returned a status of 404 when verifying the URL
> 'Resolve.html'. This may be okay if the Tracking page is in a
> different directory.
>
> The server returned a status of 404 when verifying the URL
> 'Empty.gif'. This may be okay if the Tracking page is in a different
> directory.
>
> The server returned a status of 404 when verifying the URL
> 'Error.html'. This may be okay if the Tracking page is in a different
> directory.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is? If you're just worried about those warnings, you don't have to be. They have nothing to do with synchronization (and also they aren't blocking errors in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the title of this question, the log files for the Audience Manager Synchronization service are located in a folder you configure in OutboundEmail.xml. The default is the "log" folder of your Tridion / SDL Web installation (i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\log" in SDL Web 8).

On the other side (your presentation server), the location is configured in logback.xml.

Comment: Thanks Peter kjaer, yes i found logs configured in OutboundEmail.xml , creating a separate ticket for the actual issue.