# Error while syncing of subscription database and outbound email db through profile sync

Tags: core-service, outbound-email

This problem is related to :
http://[tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/error-while-syncing-subscription-db-and-outbound-email-db-through-profile-sync](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/error-while-syncing-subscription-db-and-outbound-email-db-through-profile-sync)
I am facing difficulties to sync my subscription database and audience manager database. I have configured subscription database ,I have created a synchronization target in CME,Configured it in my publication.Is there anything else i need to do?
 After configuring the logback.xml of my sync service , I got the following messages in the log.

```
2015-12-09T08:14:50 [Info] Contacting the Core Service using a pre-defined binding, as no valid custom binding was found.
2015-12-09T08:14:50 [Debug] If you intended to use a custom binding, the following information may help you troubleshoot the issue:
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.ServiceClient.ContentManagerClient.GetConfiguredCoreService()

2015-12-09T08:14:50 [Info] Created NetTcpBinding binding for endpoint net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2013/netTcp.
2015-12-09T08:14:50 [Info] Loaded CoreService client in 82 milliseconds.
2015-12-09T08:14:50 [Debug] DataSession created (Data Source=WSV000839;Initial Catalog=Tridion_cm_email;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=TMSDBUser;).
2015-12-09T08:14:50 [Debug] DataSession created (Data Source=WSV000839;Initial Catalog=Tridion_cm_email;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=TMSDBUser;).

**net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2013/netTcp.** is the coreservice url set in the ouboundEmail.xml in CMS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mention what the actual problem is, so I'm assuming you just don't see anything getting synchronized but you aren't getting any errors either.

If that is the case, there's a couple of things you might want to check:

1. Is the Synchronization service running?
2. Have you assigned one or more Address Books to the Publication - and did you check the "Synchronize" checkbox underneath the list?
3. Do you have Contacts to synchronize in those Address Books?
4. Is the "Active" checkbox on your Synchronization Target checked?
5. If your Contacts were created only on the website, did you specify an AddressBookId in your subscription page before saving? If not, they will end up in the (Unassigned Contacts) Address Book (which only gets synchronized from CD to CM, not the other way around)

If none of these things help, I'm going to need more information about what the actual issue is to help you further :)

Comment: Thanks Peter, It was 4th point which saved us. It was inactive earlier, i can see all the data in my outbound email now.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.